# Java - Ordering of numbers in an array and keep that order for an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, numbers

Java Question: I have an array of doubles and an array of strings each 26 in length. I would like the array of doubles (lets call it weights) to when going through the `Arrays.sort()` function, the strings get sorted in the same manner.
***Example:***
Before:
*Name: Bob | Weight: 3.6

Name: Steve | Weight: 11.0

Name: Thomas | Weight: 2.2*

After:
*Name: Thomas | Weight: 2.2

Name: Bob | Weight: 3.6

Name: Steve | Weight: 11.0*

I have thought about this for some time but I have no Idea how I would go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class (for example, `Person`). Implement `Comparable<Person>`. Give it two fields, `name` and `weight`. Populate an array of `Person`, and then call `Arrays.sort`. Starting with `Person`, that might look something like

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public Person(String name, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    private String name;
    private double weight;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        int r = Double.compare(this.weight, o.weight);
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
        }
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name: %s | Weight: %.1f", name, weight);
    }
}
```

And then you can print it (because it overrides `toString()`) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person[] people = { new Person("Bob", 3.6), //
            new Person("Steve", 11.0), new Person("Thomas", 2.2) };
    System.out.println("Before Sorting");
    for (Person p : people) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
    Arrays.sort(people);
    System.out.println("After Sorting");
    for (Person p : people) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
Before Sorting
Name: Bob | Weight: 3.6
Name: Steve | Weight: 11.0
Name: Thomas | Weight: 2.2
After Sorting
Name: Thomas | Weight: 2.2
Name: Bob | Weight: 3.6
Name: Steve | Weight: 11.0
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of that in code form?

Comment: @МởṇṏсĺḕMᾶṇ Have a look here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that contains a string and a double, then have an array of those, and sort them based on the doubles.